# How to pass datetime field in UTC format as a parmeter in Query in DB2

Tags: db2

I have a date time field which is coming from an external system in UTC format `2022-01-02T08:00:00.000+00:00`. This value should be queried in DB2 to determine whether the record exists or not. The date stored in DB2 is in the format `2022-01-01 08:00:00.000` Is there any way to convert the incoming date in the format `2022-01-01 08:00:00.000` ?

The final query should be something like

```
select * from table where changedate = '2022-01-02T08:00:00.000+00:00'
```

Answer (score 0):

Db2 doesn't store timestamps in a string format. Some binary format is used for that.
So, if I got you right, your question should be changed to "how to convert `YYYY-MM-DDTHH24.MI.SS.FF3XXXXXX` string representation of timestamp to the timestamp data type".
Unfortunately, there is no such a built-in pattern in the [TO_DATE / TIMESTAMP_FORMAT](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=functions-timestamp-format) function, but you can use the following expression. `T` column has the timestamp data type, and you may use this expression in the `select * from table where changedate = ...` statement.

```
SELECT
  S
, TO_DATE (TRANSLATE (SUBSTR (S, 1, 23), ' ', 'T'), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3')
+ CAST (TRANSLATE (SUBSTR (S, 24), '', ':', '') || '00' AS DEC (6)) AS T
FROM
(
VALUES 
  '2022-01-02T08:00:00.000+00:00'
, '2022-01-02T08:00:00.000+03:30'
, '2022-01-02T08:00:00.000-03:30'
) T (S)
```

| S | T |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-01-02T08:00:00.000+00:00 | 2022-01-02-08.00.00.000000 |
| 2022-01-02T08:00:00.000+03:30 | 2022-01-02-11.30.00.000000 |
| 2022-01-02T08:00:00.000-03:30 | 2022-01-02-04.30.00.000000 |